# Getting location updates in the background, right way?

Tags: android, location

I implemented location services in my app and recently I updated it to get background location updates. However, I am not sure if that is the "right way". I am using the Network location provider and call onStart to get the location updates as soon as possible (0,0). When the user minimises the app (the app goes in the background and onPause is called) I request updates not so frequently - every 30 minutes and every 200 metres. I am wondering if my logic is right and my app will get these updates in the background. I have two class variables to store the longitude and latitude values.

This is my mainActvity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public double latitude = 0.0;
public double longitude = 0.0;
private MyLocationListener locationListner;
private LocationManager locationManager;
public boolean isFirstTimeLaunchingTheApp = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //-----------MY CODE STARTS HERE-----------------
    mainActivityLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_activity_layout);
    changeWindowTopColor();
    this.mCurrent_forecast_fragment = new Current_forecast_fragment();
    this.mHourly_forecast_fragment = new Hourly_forecast_fragment();
    this.mDaily_forecast_fragment = new Daily_forecast_fragment();
    locationListner = new MyLocationListener();

    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs, mCurrent_forecast_fragment,
            mHourly_forecast_fragment, mDaily_forecast_fragment);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        if (locationManager == null) {
            getLocation();
            Log.d(TAG, "OnResume locationManager == null");
        }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getLocation();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart getLocation");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListner);
        //EVERY HALF AN HOUR
        long minTime = 30 * 60 * 1000;
        //EVERY 200 meters
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, minTime , 200 , locationListner);
    Log.d(TAG, "requestLocationUpdates in the BACKGROUND...");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(locationManager != null) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListner);
        Log.d(TAG,"removeUpdates - onDestroy");
    }
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy called");
}
public void getLocation() {
    if(!isFirstTimeLaunchingTheApp && isNetworkAvailable()){
        final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(mainActivityLayout, "Initial launch may take a bit more to load.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                    }
                });

        snackbar.show();
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"getLocation initiated...");
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
//            mCurrent_forecast_fragment.toggleRefresh();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        //check if the if the location services are enabled
        if( !isLocationServicesEnabled()) {
            alertForNoLocationEnabled();
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG,"getLocation  requestLocationUpdates...");
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListner);
        }

    } else {
        alertForNoInternet();
        Log.d(TAG, "Alert No Internet" + 366);
    }
}
 private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        Log.d(TAG,"On Location changed...");
        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
        longitude = loc.getLongitude();
        //check if this is the first time that the app starts
        //if it is not, get the forecast only with the swiperefresh layout
        if(!isFirstTimeLaunchingTheApp) {
            getForecast(latitude, longitude);
            isFirstTimeLaunchingTheApp = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requestlocationUpdate()` will call the listener's `onLocationChanged()` method each time when your location gets changed, and it will also executed in the background.

You can solve this problem either using `AsyncTask` or `Service`.

Using `Service`:

```
public class loc extends Service
{
    LocationManager loc_manager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        loc_manager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        loc_manager.requestLocationUpdates("gps",0,0,listener);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    LocationListener listener=new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }
    };
}
```

Dont forget to register your service and also location permission in the Manifest file.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I still do not understand what is wrong with my current code. The reason I do not want to use Service or AsyncTask is that my app is pretty simple - I have 3 tab fragments and one main activity. that is why I stick with only requesting location updates onPause to get background location updates